# How to select a single toggle button at a time?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a Flutter Application, How do i  select a single toggle button at a time, if i have multiple toggle buttons?

The problem is i have multiple cases with multiple choices within each case, i have 5 different cases.

```
 onPressed: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  isSelected2[index] = !isSelected2[index];

                  switch (index) {

                    //This is the other area I had to make changes
                    case 0:
                      if (isSelected2[index]) {
                        print('true');

                        _choiceA += 5;
                        _choiceB += 5;
                        _choiceC += 10;
                        _choiceD += 10;
                      } else {
                        print('false');
                        _choiceA += -5;
                        _choiceB += -5;
                        _choiceC += -10;
                        _choiceD += -10;
                      }
                      break;
```

Thank you 
Mohammad

Comment: read `ToggleButtons` official documentation - they have samples you can follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable all others to achieve desirable behavior. 
Make a list of values you want to update for each button index:

```
List values = [[5,5,10,10], [3,2,3,-5], [3,-1,3,4], [3,-8, 12,1]];
```

Then update your choices:

```
onPressed: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < isSelected.length; buttonIndex++) {
        if (buttonIndex == index) {
          isSelected[buttonIndex] = !isSelected[buttonIndex];
          if(isSelected[buttonIndex]){
            _choiceA += values[buttonIndex][0];
            _choiceB += values[buttonIndex][1];
            _choiceC += values[buttonIndex][2];
            _choiceD += values[buttonIndex][3];
          }else{
            _choiceA -= values[buttonIndex][0];
            _choiceB -= values[buttonIndex][1];
            _choiceC -= values[buttonIndex][2];
            _choiceD -= values[buttonIndex][3];
            isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
          }
        } else {
          if(isSelected[buttonIndex]){
            _choiceA -= values[buttonIndex][0];
            _choiceB -= values[buttonIndex][1];
            _choiceC -= values[buttonIndex][2];
            _choiceD -= values[buttonIndex][3];
            isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
          }  
        }
      }
    });
  },
```

Edit:
This code should be refactored

Comment: Thank you for answer  but when the button  is selected it add the sum of the four choices, i need the button  when selected to get only one choice from the four choices in the case.

Comment: Well, map your index button to 4 values, and than add values to your variables. I will update my answer.

Comment: i still didn't get it, when user can select multiple buttons at a time it works fine, but user select only one button at a time it adds the sum of the four choices.

Comment: If I understand correctly, subtract your values if button was previously selected. I will update my answer again.

Comment: @MohammadAlmutairi, what about now?

Comment: sure, great answer

Comment: when user select a toggle button and then press on a button how do i reset the toggle buttons to unselected?

Comment: @MohammadAlmutairi, `isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;` is needed if it was selected. I already updated the code.

Comment: onPressed: () {
       
                        if (isSelected1[0]) {
                          setState(() {
                            scoreTeamA();
                          });
                          });   // after the user select win, button is still selected  until the user unselect the button. How to reset the toggle buttons to unselected when win button is pressed?

Answer (score 13):

Checkout the code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SamplePage(),
    );
  }
}

class SamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SamplePageState createState() => _SamplePageState();
}

class _SamplePageState extends State<SamplePage> {
  List<bool> isSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // this is for 3 buttons, add "false" same as the number of buttons here
    isSelected = [true, false, false];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ToggleButtons Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ToggleButtons(
          children: <Widget>[
            // first toggle button
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'First',
              ),
            ),
            // second toggle button
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Second',
              ),
            ),
            // third toggle button
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Third',
              ),
            ),
          ],
          // logic for button selection below
          onPressed: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
                isSelected[i] = i == index;
              }
            });
          },
          isSelected: isSelected,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer  but when the button  is selected it add the sum of the four choices, i need the button  when selected to get only one choice from the four choices in the case.